# Which should be powered first: MOSFET driver IC (Vdd) or MOSFET bridge (Vin)

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, current, mosfet-driver

[image]

I have this [MOSFET driver IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MIC4606-85V-Full-Bridge-MOSFET-Drivers-with-Adaptive-Dead-Time-and-Shoot-Through-Protection-DS20005604.pdf).

The application circuit mentions powering the Vdd of the driver first and then only the Vin, but I did it in opposite. I powered Vin first and then Vdd. This resulted in damage of the MOSFET driver IC.

I know I should have followed the recommendations mentioned in the datasheet/user guide of the MOSFET driver, but I have a general question.

- Should Vin be powered first and then only the Vdd of the MOSFET driver for all MOSFET driver ICs, or can we power vice-versa?
- Why did the MOSFET driver IC fail when I powered Vin first before Vdd? What might have happened? Any idea?

Edit: [User guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC4606%20Evaluation%20Board%20UG%2050002980A.pdf). Page 12, point 5 mentions about power sequence.

Comment: The application circuit in your question powers them both together so, why have you shown this?

Comment: `The Application circuit mentions powering the Vdd of the Driver first and then only the Vin.` in the circuit shown how is it possible to apply Vdd first then Vin? Even if Vin on its own is applied both Vin and Vdd will be applied pretty much at the same time (neglecting the delay of the linear regulator). Also, can you put the excerpt of the statement or at least indicate which document and which page it's on?

Comment: 'which should be powered first' as a generic question is impossible to answer. It depends on the details of the circuit. Some circuits are built so they will tolerate other parts powered off, some circuits require a specific sequence of power rails being brought up, it all depends on the design details.

Comment: @Andyaka, Just to explain my question, I showed this circuit.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, regarding the power sequencing, please check the edit once.

Comment: @Neil_UK, Can you please check the edit and also, can you tell me what is wrong in powering Vin first before Vdd with the MIC406 MOSFET driver?

Comment: You need to post the schematic of the circuit that gives you access to Vdd and Vin separately. The circuit you currently have is meaningless to your question.

Comment: @Andyaka, I don't have that circuit diagram with me now. Just trying to find the root cause on why - powering Vin before Vdd causes damaged to the IC?

Comment: My comment remains the same.

Comment: it's not clear what page 12 point 5 is referring to, I can't find a Vin on the board. I wonder if they mean VBUS? Maybe it's something to do with the bootstrap caps? The circuit you've shown will apply Vdd later than Vin, as the regulator will take some time to charge the Vdd capacitor. Is that the rail application difference you are talking about? Or are you actually using a circuit that's different to the one you've shown. If so, my vote is with Andy.

Comment: @Neil_UK, Vin refers to the voltge on the MOSFETs drain. Vdd refers to the MOSFET driver ICs power supply. I am using a circuit different to the one that is shown in the question, where Vdd and Vin are powered separately.